# How to search and generate substrings

Tags: swift

Here's what I'm trying to do, in Python code (may be the more precise explanation):

```
name = "#1: Joe Smith"
name = name[name.find(" "):]
```

Basically, trying to create a substring of everything after the first space and since Swift doesn't have an easy way of using integer indexes to generate substrings, it has generated a great amount of struggle for me.

Here's my attempt in Swift:

```
var name:String = "#1: Joe Smith"
var intIndex: Int = distance(name.startIndex, name.rangeOfString(" ").startIndex)
var startIndex = advance(" ".startIndex, intIndex)
var endIndex = advance(" ".startIndex, 0)
var substring: String = name[startIndex...endIndex]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there's no need to use `advance` or `distance`. Since you're looking for everything **after** the space, we can use the `endIndex` from the range returned from `rangeOfString` as the `startIndex` of the range we use for to get the substring.

```
let name = "#1: Joe Smith"
if let spaceRange = name.rangeOfString(" ") {
    // Get the substring from the character after the space to the end of the string
    let substring = name[spaceRange.endIndex..<name.endIndex]
    println(substring) // Joe Smith
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanted to separate the whole string into two different parts, such that the first string found divides the string into two parts. Here is my attempt to do so,

```
extension String{
  subscript(search: String ) -> [String]?{
    let startIndex = self.startIndex
    let endIndex = self.endIndex
    let range = self.rangeOfString(search, options: NSStringCompareOptions.allZeros, range: Range(start: startIndex, end: endIndex), locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())
    if let theRange = range{
      let startIndex = advance(theRange.startIndex, -1)
      let endRange = Range(start: theRange.endIndex, end:self.endIndex)

       return [
         self.substringToIndex(startIndex),
         self.substringWithRange(endRange)
      ]
    }
    return nil
  }

}

let a = "Hello, Mr. Andy"
a[" "]
// ["Hello", "Mr. Andy"]

let b = "My address is Tammisto, Vaanta"
join("", b["Tammisto,"]!)
// My address is Vaanta
```